# Should this be viewed as a serious issue with the meadow-theoretic approach?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, field-theory

Meadow theory (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0823)) allows us to apply the results and concepts of universal algebra to the study of fields. Obviously, this is very, *very* nice.

However, I have the following issue with the meadow-theoretic approach: since every meadow satisfies $0^{-1}=0,$ and since this makes reciprocation in both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ discontinuous (at $0$), thus these number systems cannot be viewed as models of the theory of meadows in the category $\mathrm{Top}$ unless we endow them with a non-standard topology.

**Questions.**

1. Should this be viewed as a serious issue with the meadow-theoretic approach?
2. Does anyone know of a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to study! When you are interested in topological questions, then obviously topological meadows don't include topological fields. In my opinion the natural definition of a topological field should be a (commutative) topological ring $K$ whose underlying ring is also a field such that the map $K^* \to K^*, x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous.

Probably a more natural approach would be to replace $K$ by $K \cup \{\infty\}$ and define $0^{-1} := \infty$, $\infty^{-1} := 0$, and built up an axiomatization around this idea. In other words, work with the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ instead of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1_K$.

PS: I wonder why the well-known Von Neumann regular commutative rings are called meadows as if this was a new concept.

Comment: Every meadow is a regular ring in the sense of von Neumann, but the homomorphisms are (in principle) different.

Comment: @Zhen: What is an example of a homomorphism of von Neumann regular rings which is not a homomorphism of meadows?

Comment: I don't know, but there should be one. After all, homomorphisms of von Neumann regular rings are just homomorphisms of rings, which may not preserve the "weak" inverses (which are not always unique).

Comment: The weak inverses are unique (recall that $b$ is a weak inverse of $a$ if $aba=a$ but also $bab=b$).

Comment: The definition of von Neumann regular ring only asks for one of those two equations, however.

Comment: @ZhenLin :  If you know of a commutative von Neumann-regular ring (ᴄᴠNʀʀ) that can be made into a meadow in two different ways, then the identity map is an isomorphism of ᴄᴠNʀʀs that's not an isomorphism between the two meadows.  And of course, if there's a ᴄᴠNʀʀ that can't be made into a meadow at all, then the concepts are different.  So meadows are the same as ᴄᴠNʀʀs if and only if each ᴄᴠNʀʀ can be made into a meadow in a unique way.  (I don't know if that's true or not!)